# the method "sendOtp" isn't defined for class 'LoginPage'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i am calling this method(sendOtp) from another class but getting error: the method "sendOtp" isn't defined for class 'LoginPage'
it is a phone authentication loginpage method to sendOtp

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return LoginPageState();
  }
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

Future<void> sendOtp() async {
 final PhoneVerificationCompleted phoneVerificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential credential) {};
    final PhoneVerificationFailed phoneVerificationFailed =
        (AuthException exception) {
      print("Login Faild due to $exception");
    };
    final PhoneCodeSent phoneCodeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
    };
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      print("time out");
    };
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _numberController.text,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 120),
        verificationCompleted: phoneVerificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: phoneVerificationFailed,
        codeSent: phoneCodeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }
```

----------------ANOTHER CLASS-------------------

```
class OtpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _name,_number, _id;
  OtpScreen(this._name, this._number, this._id);
  @override
  OtpScreenState createState() {
    return OtpScreenState();
  }
}

class OtpScreenState extends State<OtpScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _otpController = TextEditingController();
  var _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  LoginPage loginPage = LoginPage();
 Widget resend() {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text("Send Otp again"),
      onPressed: () => loginPage.sendOtp(),    //ERROR IS HERE: sendOtp isn't defined for class LoginPage
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This cannot do with Flutter because `LoginPage` is a widget not just a plain class. You can create a simple class for that method to use like the way you are using.

Comment: How are you adding `OtpScreen` to widget tree? can you show that code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call a method of another `class` without any reference. If the method is in the parent `widget`, you can pass it down when calling the child `widget`. If the method is in the child, you can pass a `GlobalKey` from the parent to the child, add that key to the child, and then through the `key` call the methods of the child.

If the two widgets have no relation what-so-ever, then you would benefit from using an `InheritedWidget` or a State Management solution that allows you to pass methods around in your app.